# footer at the bottom, but clear float dont work

Tags: html, css

Maybe i did not get enough coffee today, but i can remember how to do that

i have

```
header
content
   float float
footer
```

so the content have two float element

The problem, the footer don't go at the bottom.... it's up...

I cannot put the footer INSIDE the content (for background problem)
I have made an empty div the is clear:float : don't work
the clear float on the footer : don't work either

so i am lost... can you help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously you didn't have enough coffee.

It's `clear: both`, silly ;)

Comment: ok your right... but it dont get the content the height of the two box included in .. it just pop the footer at the bottom...

Comment: clear:both; clear:float; sound similar... ah ! getting old an dummy !

Comment: To get the lenght of the content... i will have to use the empty float, right ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I think you may be looking for a clear:both inside the content <div>. Is this what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/ZCgMM/11/

Answer (score 0):

You could use either of the following methods;

```
footer {
clear: both;
}
```

Or,

```
content {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Hope that helps.